# Align elements in middle

Tags: html, css

I have the following page:

[Page on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uSiTOpU/1/edit)

If you look at the top-right-hand corner, then you can see that the settings & chat pic and the username is aligning with the lower border of the profile picture.

How could I make all elements in top-right-hand-corner align in the middle of the top-bar?

The top-bar is supposed to look like that: [image]

EDIT: I have applied the vertical-align: middle property to these elements. However, as you can see at ranganadh's [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uSiTOpU/9/edit), the image seems to be a bit too near to the lower corner. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `vertical-align:middle` property to class `.top-right-button`

change to

```
.top-right-button{
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

Check [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uSiTOpU/9/edit)

Comment: Thank you so far, mind checking out the edit to the post? It caused another problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your CSS as follows:

```
.right-stuff {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed, bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.top-right-button {
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The `vertical-align` property is not inherited and must be specified explicitly.

By default, your right most image is aligned with the default baseline of the container block.  Setting vertical align to `middle` gives a more pleasing view.

If you need to, use the `bottom` offset to adjust the overall vertical position of the `.right-stuff` block.

See demo at http://jsbin.com/uSiTOpU/16/edit

Comment: Thank you so far, mind checking out the edit to the post? It caused another problem.

Comment: See updated post, specifically using the `bottom` offset value.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understand your edit well.
Try to change

```
#top-right-profile-image {
margin-top: 5px;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background-color: #ffffff;
```

}

to

```
#top-right-profile-image {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
background-color: #ffffff;
```

}

It gives a better looking result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply need to add an valign="top" to your profile image.

```
<img valign="top" class="top-right-button" id="top-right-profile-image" src="//www.placehold.it/20x20"/ >
```